Angular 17 Hydration failed to enable when serving the application
I upgraded angular 12 up to angular 17 and now I'm experiencing the following warning pop-up in my console when serving my angular application locally via ng serve.
NG0505: Angular hydration was requested on the client, but there was no serialized information present in the server response, thus hydration was not enabled. Make sure the `provideClientHydration()` is included into the list of providers in the server part of the application configuration. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0505
I am using NgModule and I am providing 'provideClientHydration' inside my app.module.ts file. As mentioned inside Angular's documentation for Hydration https://v17.angular.io/guide/hydration.
I provide the following files related to server-side rending within my application.
server.ts
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';
import { join } from 'node:path';
import AppServerModule from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')
    : join(distFolder, 'index.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Server static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', (req, res, next) => {
    next();
  }, express.static(join(distFolder), { maxAge: '1y', fallthrough: false }));

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: distFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();

export default AppServerModule;

main.server.ts
export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server';

main.ts
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});

app.module.server.ts (here's where the AppModule is imported which I understand 'provideClientHydration' gets included with the server)
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}

app.module.ts (simplified)
...
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { APP_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SessionModule } from './session/session.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'accessibility', data: { title: 'Accessibility'}, loadChildren: () => import('./accessibility/accessibility.module').then(m => m.AccessibilityModule) },
      { path: 'bag',           data: { title: 'Bag'          }, loadChildren: () => import('./shopping-bag/shopping-bag.module')  .then(m => m.ShoppingBagModule) },
      { path: 'faq',           data: { title: 'FAQ'          }, loadChildren: () => import('./faq/faq.module')                    .then(m => m.FAQModule) },
      { path: '',              data: { title: ''             }, loadChildren: () => import('./landing/landing.module')            .then(m => m.LandingModule) },
      { path: '**',            data: { title: ''             }, loadChildren: () => import('./error/error.module')                .then(m => m.ErrorModule) }
    ], { anchorScrolling: 'enabled', scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }),
    SessionModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [
    [{ provide: APP_ID, useValue: 'webapp' }],
    provideClientHydration() // providing provideClientHydration here
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


As far as I can tell I am providing 'provideClientHydration' to the server on bootstrap. I'm not sure what I may be missing or where to look to help debug this further. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

please share the github repo, also main.ts and main.server.ts

please replicate the issue on this stackblitz and share back!

I went ahead and created a very simple new project using the same dependencies and server-side step-up I have with hydration displaying the same warning message I'm seeing in the browser's console. Please let me know if this helps thank you.
https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Malstar21/website-test?file=package.json

Thank you for the stackblitz, I ran both ng serve and npm run dev:ssr Both did not show any errors in browser console, could you let me know the exact steps for replicating the issue on the stackblitz, also a screenshot of the error in stackblitz, thank you!

Once running the application via ng serve I clicked open in a new tab on the upper right-hand corner of the application window. Once in a new tab when I inspect the console I see the NG0505 warning message.
